# SQL Server Express 2008 Install Side-by-side w/ SQL 2005 Express Fails

Tags: sql-server

When I try to install a new instance of SQL Server 2008 Express on a development machine with SQL 2005 Express already up and running, the install validation fails because the "SQL 2005 Express tools" are installed and I'm told to remove them.

**What exactly does that mean?**

After reading this article:

http://www.asql.biz/Articoli/SQLX08/Art1_5.aspx

I uninstalled the 2005 version of the SQL Management Studio but received the same error from the 2008 installer during my follow-up attempt.

**Updates**

1) Uninstalled the SQL 2005 Management Studio only.  Received the same error from the 2008 install.

2) Removed all SQL 2005 common components.  Received the same error from the 2008 install.

3) Installed the shared components from the SQL 2008 installation program.  Received the same error from the 2008 install when trying to install the new SQL 2008 instance.

4) Uninstalled SQL 2008 components, rebooted, re-installed SQL 2005 Management Studio from installation media, rebooted, un-installed SQL 2005 Workstation Components from Control Panel, re-booted.

Installation of SQL 2008 is now proceeding as it should.

Seems likely that if I'd re-booted after update 2 above things would have gone more smoothly.  :-(

Comment: In my case i have uninstalled "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express". This is the old software for SQL 2005 Express. There ist **no 2005** in the name!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Although you should have no problem running a 2005 instance of the database engine beside a 2008 instance, The tools are installed into a shared directory, so you can't have two versions of the tools installed. Fortunately, the 2008 tools are backwards-compatible. As we speak, I'm using SSMS 2008 and Profiler 2008 to manage my 2005 Express instances. Works great.

Before installing the 2008 tools, you need to remove any and all "shared" components from 2005. Try going to your Add/Remove programs control panel, find Microsoft SQL Server 2005, and click "Change." Then choose "Workstation Components" and remove everything there (this will not remove your database engine).

I believe the 2008 installer also has an option to upgrade shared components only. You might try that. Good luck!

Comment: That's good news!  But do you know what pieces of 2005 Express I need to remove to convince the installer to proceed?

Answer (score 16):

In my case even after uninstalling all 2005 related components it didn't worked. I had to resort to a brute force way and [remove following registry keys](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/5fc58507-9f40-4213-acbd-32a57c8822d7)

**32 Bit OS**: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\90

**64 Bit OS**: HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\90

Comment: to help decipher HKLM -> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

Answer (score 2):

I had to unistall the Workstation Components and SSMS Tools Pack (SSMS Tools Pack is an add-in for Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) including SSMS Express.)
Installation of SQL 2008 is now proceeding as it should.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that SQL 2008 MS has a bug where connecting to a remote server (say like a service provider collocation) it will always try to open the fist db in the list, and since the possibilities of been ur db the first on the list are really low, it will throw and error and fail to display the list of dbs... which using sql 2005 management studio it just works.

Wished I could use SQL 2008 MS, but looks like as far I connect to remote SQL 2005, SQL 2008 is out of the question on my dev machine :(

Answer (score 0):

Just Remove the the Workstation Components from Add/Remove Programs - SQL Server 2005.
Removing Workstation Components, SQL Server 2008 installation goes well.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express 2005 from control panel

Comment: My control panel just says "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express"... but doesn't mention if it's 2000 or 2005 or 2008 or what.  Ugh.  Thanks loads Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

N.B. These notes are for SQL Server Express 2008 R2 (so Microsoft still haven't made this any easier).  I also realise that I complicated things by installing 32-bit SQL Server Express 2005 and 64-bit SQL Server Express 2008.

I followed the steps by [Josh Hinman above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175881/sql-server-express-2008-install-side-by-side-w-sql-2005-express-fails/175894#175894).  Uninstalling the SQL Server Express 2005 "Workstation Components" was not enough.  I required an uninstall of the 2005 Management Studio as well.

I also tried the Upgrade route that Josh Hinman suggested by clicking on the 'Upgrade from SQL Server 2000, SQL Server 2005 or SQL Server 2008'.  This route never gave me the option of installing the components side-by-side it just went straight through the process of upgrading from 2005 to 2008.  It completed successfully - but hadn't actually done anything.  Thankfully though it hadn't harmed any existing database instances.  So be warned trying that route.

Answer (score 0):

If you currently have Red Gate SQL Toolbelt, you will need to unistall that too before continuing. Somehow it adds a reference to the 2005 version of the SQL Management Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I'am trying to install SQL SERVER developer 2008 R2 alongside SQL SERVER 2005 EXPRESS,

i went to program features, clicked on unistall SQL SERVER 2005 EXPRESS, and only checked, WORKSTATION COMPONENTS, it unistalled: support files, sql mngmt studio

After that installation of sql 2008 r2 developer went ok....

Hopes this helps somebody

Answer (score 0):

I also had to remove the SMSS before it would get past that step.