# Can you have a SQL Express 2005 and SQL Express 2008R2 instance on the same machine?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, sql-server-express

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server Express 2008 Install Side-by-side w/ SQL 2005 Express Fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175881/sql-server-express-2008-install-side-by-side-w-sql-2005-express-fails)

I was wondering if you can have a SQL Express 2005 and a SQL Express 2008R2 instance installed on the same machine (OS: Windows 7).

I don't see why you can't? Someone at work told me you can't, but I have multiple SQL Express 2008 instances on my machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes; you can freely mix SQL Server 2005 and any flavor (R2 or not) of SQL Server 2008, and you can have multiple instances of both. 2005 and 2008 do not share any components, so they may as well be two completely independent products.

The only versions of SQL Server that can clash are 2008 with 2008 R2. Installing instances of 2008 and 2008 R2 on the same machine is not supported, as they have shared components that are different versions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can install multiple instances of SQL Server.  Different versions, same versions...

You'll run out of resources (RAM, hard drive space) first....

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, I do on Windows 7.  I installed SQL Server 2008 R2 last and installed it as named instance.