# Can't install Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (R2) Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

EDIT: solved! read below

When I want to install MS SQL Server 2008 (R2) on my Win7 PC, I keep getting the error that I need to remove my SQL Server 2005 Express. This is, however, no longer installed.
[image]

I followed the same routine as here: [SQL Server Express 2008 Install Side-by-side w/ SQL 2005 Express Fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175881/sql-server-express-2008-install-side-by-side-w-sql-2005-express-fails) without result.

I deleted everything linking to SQL Server 2005 and tried to install the 2008, same error ...
Reinstalled 2005 and tried to update via the 2008 setup, "can't find 2005 shared modules to update"
Deleted 2005, rebooted, ran 2008 setup, same error: need to remove 2005 Express
Reinstalled 2005, deleted shared modules, tried to install 2008, same error as above
Completely deleted 2005, rebooted, ran setup, still 2005 on the system?!

I ran the setup this time again and installed everything except the Menegement Studio.
Too bad this is the one program I definitly need to follow my classes.

I hope you guy can help me with this!

PS: I've got a lot of SQL programs installed, because I've got Visual Studio, SQLyog, ... installed for my studies

**SOLUTION**
Found someone with the same problem: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/5fc58507-9f40-4213-acbd-32a57c8822d7/
How I solved my problem: As I have a 64bit system, I had to remove this registerfolder: *HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\90*
For 32bit systems: remove *HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\90*

Comment: Could they be referring to VS 2005 Express?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same issue before. It's not about SQL Server 2005 Express, you may have some add-on installed for SQL Server 2005.

Here is my solution:

1. run Regedit
2. Check HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\ShellSEM
3. If it exists, rename "ShellSEM" to anything
4. Run SQL server 2008 installation again

Comment: I finally dared to make changes in my register.  
Most register-related answers were for 32bit machines, but finally found a 64bit answer and I deleted the while /90/ folder.  

It finally works :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried uninstalling SSMS? (SQL Server Management Studio Express)  Unless you know that you downloaded a newer version (2008), it may just not be reporting the version in the programs window.