# Remove sql server 2005 express tools to Install SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I was trying to install SQL Server 2008 Express edition, and installation wizard was not allowing me to proceed further unless I remove SQL Server 2005 Express tools.
I tried removing SQL Server 2005 Express tools from Uninstall Program window, but still the same error continues.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server Express 2008 Install Side-by-side w/ SQL 2005 Express Fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175881/sql-server-express-2008-install-side-by-side-w-sql-2005-express-fails)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Solution

1. Open Run Menu and type regedit.
2. It will open Registry Editor
3. Now go to following location.

(32Bit) **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > Software > Microsoft > Microsoft SQL Server > 90**

(64Bit) **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > Software > Wow6432Node > Microsoft > Microsoft SQL Server > 90**

Remove Registry Key 90.

Now try to install SQL Server 2008 and it would work this time.

Comment: For those that are not happy editing registry keys, I just renamed the node to see if this fixed my issue without breaking anything.  It worked, so I later deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem just now. I know it's a late answer but I fixed it without touching the registry.

The problem was the old SQL server Management Studio Express (in my case).

I don't know if the problem can be fixed by uninstalling this software by the native windows uninstaller.

**My solution**

1. Download and run https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/290301/en-us (I used it in windows xp and I think that link will let you download new different application for vista/7/8).
2. Choice you have a problem with uninstalling software and select **Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express** (or enterprice or somethink, depends on currently installed version).

The "fix-it" application will try to uninstall the software, after the uninstallation success, you can Install newer version of SQL server.

Just in my case this worked. I using Windows XP.

Answer (score -1):

In my case I had to remove Server 2005 from Add remove programs to fix the issue (didn't even have Express 2005 - despite the error complaining about Express 2005).